# Including OR in a regex pattern (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Trying to create a pattern that includes an **or** condition.

```
$pattern["body"]='/(<\/a><\/li><\/ul><\/div><p>|<h2>)(.*)<div class="like">/s';
```

The pattern should recognize any text between a series of "`<\/a><\/li><\/ul><\/div><p>`" **or** a "`<h2>`" as the beginning delimiter, but apparently the or condition does not work in this case.
Anyone can offer a hint for the correct syntax!? I am striving for 1 hour and I have lost the focus and patience in this rule.
THank you in advance.

Comment: You specified `ereg` in the question title. I should point out that the `ereg` functions in PHP have been deprecated and shouldn't be used any more. You should be using the `preg_` fuctions instead. See the PHP manual for more.

Comment: Sorry! I ment regex. I will change the subject

Comment: [NO REGEX HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"(?<=</a></li></ul></div>|<h2>).*"
```

see below grep test:

```
kent$  echo "</a></li></ul></div>something"|grep -Po "(?<=</a></li></ul></div>|<h2>).*"                                                  
something

kent$  echo "<h2>something"|grep -Po "(?<=</a></li></ul></div>|<h2>).*"                                                                  
something
```

Comment: Thank you! 
What does the ?<= do?

Comment: @Armand go to http://docs.python.org/library/re.html, and search "(?<=" you will see.

Comment: Thank you. That means that there was a need for _positive lookahead assertion_

Comment: Actually that's a *positive **lookbehind** assertion*

Answer (score 0):

```
'%(</a></li></ul></div><p>|<h2>)(.*)<div class="like">%s'
```

I don't have any sample data to test against but it looks like you were there. I only changed the delimiter so it wouldn't have to be escaped, I find it's easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
For some unclear reason it does not work, but the example provided above from Kent works.

Comment: @Armand - so, then the differences are the extra `<p>` and the trailing `<div class="like">` in the regex. If Kent's worked then your problem statement is incorrect.

Comment: I added the extra <p> and the <div class="like"> in Kent's code. The secret was the ?<=

Comment: If you added the extra's back, I would say your lucky that it apparently PHP (PCRE) allows alternation with its fixed length lookbehinds. As soon as there is a spurrious whitespace between tags it might fail.

Answer (score 0):

This might work http://www.ideone.com/zYB1n
But, I'm no php expert.

```
$regex = '/(?:<\/a>\s*<\/li>\s*<\/ul>\s*<\/div>\s*<p>|<h2>)(?<Text>[\S\s]*)(?=<div class="like">)/';
if (preg_match( $regex, $str1, $matches ))
  print_r( $matches['Text'] );
```